# On some devices, data is not saved in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

Screenshots:

[When the image is saved, it is displayed in the table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI2CW.png)

[Data lost after restart the app and table view is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJet1.png)

I have my own data model which I store in **UserDefualts** under a specific key using encoding and decoding.
There is **UserDefaults** extension for data managing

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func saveResult(result: ComputedResult) {
        if var results = try? results(forKey: "results") {
            removeAllResults()
            results.append(result)
            try? set(results: results, forKey: "results")
        } else {
            try? set(results: [result], forKey: "results")
        }
    }
    
    func updateResults(result: ComputedResult, index: Int) {
        var newResults = try! results(forKey: "results")
        removeAllResults()
        newResults[index] = result
        try? set(results: newResults, forKey: "results")
    }
    
    func removeResult(index: Int) {
        var newResults = try! results(forKey: "results")
        removeAllResults()
        newResults.remove(at: index)
        try? set(results: newResults, forKey: "results")
    }
    
    func removeAllResults() {
        removeObject(forKey: "results")
    }
}
```

This function is for fetching data from UserDefaults

```
func fetchResults() {
    self.results = []
    self.results = try! UserDefaults.standard.results(forKey: "results")
}
```

I have no idea why the data is not saved only on some devices.
Please, help me to solve this issue

Comment: First, I would suggest to remove all the `try?` and implement a correct error checking. Maybe this will give you a hint.

Comment: Do you call `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` at the end? This will save all your pending changes.

Comment: @Septronic No, see the docs: `synchronize()`
Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; **this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize